# How can I use shared components between routes in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm thinking of migrating from create-react-app to Next.js
I need to share component between routes in Next.js
I tried the Layout file example below and it worked pretty well for me but I have a special case where I need the shared component to be above the router itself.

For example, if I have a video element and want the video to still playing if I changed the route

```
const Layout = (props) => (
  <div>
      {props.children}
      <video width="400" controls>
        <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
        Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
      </video>

  </div>
)
```

```
const Home = () => (
  <Layout>
    <Link href="/about"><a>About</a></Link>
    <h1 className='title'>Welcome to Home!</h1>
  </Layout>
)
```

```
const About = () => (
  <Layout>
    <Link href="/"><a>Home</a></Link>
    <h1 className='title'>Welcome to About!</h1>
  </Layout>
)
```

Example from another project using create-react-app and reach-router
the player component is above the router

```
<Layout>
    <Player/>
    <Router className={'router'}>
        <Login path={Routes.login}/>
        <NotFound404 default/>
        <Home path={Routes.root}/>
        <Test path={Routes.test}/>
    </Router>
<Layout/>
```

The shared element will be the video tag, the problem is on every route change the video is rendered and replayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might wanna check the docs on using `pages/_app.js` for that.

Example usage is shown below:

```
import Head from "next/head";

type Props = {
  pageProps: any;
  Component: React.FC;
};

const App = ({ Component, pageProps }: Props) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        // You can put whatever you want to put in your document head
      </Head>

      <YourSharedComponent />

      <Component {...pageProps} />

      <style>{`
        // styles...
      `}</style>
    </>
  );
};

App.getInitialProps = async ({ Component }) => {
  const pageProps = Component.getInitialProps && await Component.getInitialProps(ctx, loggedUser);

  return {
    pageProps,
  }
};

export default App;
```